# how to check if BLAS and ATLAS already installed

Tags: linux, lapack, blas, armadillo, atlas

I'm trying to install armadillo library onto my linux system(ubuntu 12.04). The BOOST BLAS ATLAS and LAPACK is required first for the installation. Is there a way to check if those libraries are already installed or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these libraries are in the default repository, so you can easily get them by

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack3
```

etc. I understand that this is not quite an answer to your question, but this is what you will probably have to do anyway. In case you still want to check if a package (any, not just libraries listed above) is installed, just run

```
apt-cache policy liblapack3
```

Comment: How did you know to type liblapack3 rather than just lapack?  What exactly would you type for the other libraries mentioned?  Also, when you type sudo apt-get install liblapack3 , I suppose that apt-get first checks if liblapack3 is already installed?  (Sorry for my noob questions.)

Comment: It does check, of course, but sometimes you may want to know whether it is install and do not install it in case it is not. For other libraries (if I remember right) you should type libblas3 or libblas-dev, libatlas-dev (use TAB key to view hints, as I am not sure about these packages) and libboost-all-dev if you need full boost library. Again, use TAB key to install certain components only.

Comment: I get E: Unable to locate package liblapack3. Perhaps the package is outdated? Is there another way?